# Fibonacci using Matrix Representation.

Tags: matrices, fibonacci-numbers, matrix-exponential

Fibonacci using matrix representation is of the form :
[Fibonacci Matrix](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N70mg.png). This claims to be of `O(log n)`.However, isn't computing matrix multiplication of order `O(n^3)` or using Strassen's algorithm `O(n^2.81)`? How can this be solved in `O(log n)`?

Comment: I suspect they use mathematical results specific to this (rather simple) matrix to produce a calculation that does not need the full blown matrix multiply and is, instead, only $O(\log{n})$.

Comment: You mean to say that, this matrix is a special case of finding matrix exponentiation in `0(log n)`?

Comment: I'm saying that I suspect that the recurrence you get from the matrix multiply has some special property such that the result can be calculated without going through the full-blown matrix multiplication.  I haven't done this myself, by the way.  It's just my speculation.  (Though I think it's well founded.)  Its "$O$", by the way, not "zero".

Comment: Those are completely different $n$'s.  Computing the $n$-th Fibonacci number takes time $O(\log n)$.  Multiplying two matrices of size $k$ takes time $O(k^{2.81})$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, using Fibonacci Matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ is the way to calculate the nth fibonacci number in $O(log(n))$ time. You can apply [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring) to the matrix, and the solution is reduced to $O(log(n))$.

I put an example code.

```
long long fibonacci(int n)
{
    long long fib[2][2]= {{1,1},{1,0}},ret[2][2]= {{1,0},{0,1}},tmp[2][2]= {{0,0},{0,0}};
    int i,j,k;
    while(n)
    {
        if(n&1)
        {
            memset(tmp,0,sizeof tmp);
            for(i=0; i<2; i++) for(j=0; j<2; j++) for(k=0; k<2; k++)
                        tmp[i][j]=(tmp[i][j]+ret[i][k]*fib[k][j]);
            for(i=0; i<2; i++) for(j=0; j<2; j++) ret[i][j]=tmp[i][j];
        }
        memset(tmp,0,sizeof tmp);
        for(i=0; i<2; i++) for(j=0; j<2; j++) for(k=0; k<2; k++)
                    tmp[i][j]=(tmp[i][j]+fib[i][k]*fib[k][j]);
        for(i=0; i<2; i++) for(j=0; j<2; j++) fib[i][j]=tmp[i][j];
        n/=2;
    }
    return (ret[0][1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Matrix multiplication is $O(n^{2.81})$, where $n$ is the size of the matrix.  The matrix size is constant here ($n = 2$).  So each matrix multiplication takes constant time.

If we want $f_k$, there are $\log k$ matrix multiplications needed.  Each takes constant time, so the total time is $O(\log k)$.